# Lua: attempt to perform arithmetic on a string value

Tags: string, lua, string-concatenation

I'm trying to add a string to a returned value in lua:

```
local function func(str)
   return (str+"_something")
end

print(func("ABC"))
```

and I'm getting an error:

> "attempt to perform arithmetic on local 'str' (a string value)"

or this error (in my original program):

> @user_script:1: user_script:1: attempt to perform arithmetic on a string value

I tried to use tosring(str)+"_something" but didn't help...

so how to Concatenate a string in Lua ?

Comment: `getmetatable''.__add = function(a,b)return a..b end`

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff, this does not work if the strings contain numbers: `"1"+"2"` is the number `3`, not the string `"12"`.

Comment: @lhf - Ops!  Forgot about this weird feature.  Auto-coercion from string to other datatype is rather unnatural.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

see "Concatenation" in [this link](http://lua-users.org/wiki/StringsTutorial):
http://lua-users.org/wiki/StringsTutorial

The solution is to use the `..`, as in example:

```
local function func(str)
   return (str.." WORLD")
end

print(func("HELLO"))
```

that's should return:

> HELLO WORLD

Comment: So you did it yourself. Kudos