# Attempt to perform arithmetic on field 'duration' (a string value)

Tags: lua

Here is my error message:

Panel: [name:DItemSlot][class:Panel][138,69,64,64]

[ERROR] addons/pointshop2/lua/ps2/client/notifications/cl_knotificationpanelmanager.lua:91: attempt to perform arithmetic on field 'duration' (a string value)
  1. unknown - addons/pointshop2/lua/ps2/client/notifications/cl_knotificationpanelmanager.lua:91

And here is my code:

```
if not self.panelSlidingIn and #self.notificationsWaiting > 0 then
    self.panelSlidingIn = table.remove( self.notificationsWaiting, 1 ) --
    Dequeue
    self.panelSlidingIn:SetParent( self )
    self.panelSlidingIn:SetVisible( true )
    self.panelSlidingIn.slideOutStart = CurTime( ) + 
    self.panelSlidingIn.duration + self.slideInDuration
    self.slidingStarted = CurTime( )
    table.insert( self.notifications, self.panelSlidingIn )
    surface.PlaySound( self.panelSlidingIn.sound or 
    "kreport/misc_menu_4.wav" )
end
```

I don't know what is happening, and I can't seem to fix it either.

Answer (score 0):

When you use `+` operator on string Lua tries to convert them to numbers. If it couldn't it gives you such errors. If you want to concatinate strings use operator `..` instead. If you want to make arithmetics, make sure strings have convertable values.

Similar question: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21362374/lua-attempt-to-perform-arithmetic-on-a-string-value).

Comment: I think it's an outright duplicate.